# Remove Import action from Recently Viewed list view (LEX)

Tags: lightning-experience, list-view

We have a list view that we use in our AppExchange product. Somehow Recently Viewed list view has Import button that seems broken and is useless for us - we have our own Import button!

Is there a way to remove this button?

Or perhaps there's a way to set default list view other than recently viewed?

[image: import button image]

Comment: Worth noting I've tried using `actionOverrides` in object xml, but it didn't work for Import button...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can check, You can not remove it from the search layout of the object. You can manage this through profile permission.

To remove the Import Button on Lightning for Accounts and Contacts Objects please DeSelect the "Import Personal Contacts / Import personal accounts and contacts." on profile. It also requires the create and edit permission on the object level.

[image]

Comment: Yep, but most of our users will be admins who 99% likely will have this permission enabled on their profile anyway...